# AviarySDK iOS 7.1 Supporting arm64?

Tags: ios, aviary

I just upgraded to XCode 5.1 and iOS 7.1.  It doesn't seem like Aviary compiles when arm64 is included in the Valid Architectures.  I just upgraded to Aviary 3.1.1 today and didn't notice the latest SDK fixes the issue.

When will Aviary support iOS 7.1 and the arm64 architecture?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be asking this at the Aviary website, not here.

Comment: @rmaddy yep did that. Asking community tho if anyone has the same issue.